# How to not open duplicate windows, in different browser tabs, on different pages?

Tags: javascript, html, window

Before you mark this as a duplicate, please read through it.

So, my client might open two windows, one with this URL:

```
/foo/bar/
```

And one with this one:

```
/foo/john/
```

They both contain this code:

```
window.open("/foo/gist/", "afoopage", "etc");
```

When my clients open both those windows, he/she gets duplicate windows opened, with the same content (`/foo/gist/`).

How do I prevent or stop this, and if there is no solution (which there probably is, judging from online content), how can I recognise with JavaScript that duplicate windows have been opened, and close one or two?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce in latest Firefox (Windows 7). What's your browser? Have you double-checked that you're setting exactly the same window name?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Google Chrome latest version, Mac OS X.

Comment: Right... Apparently, it's a [known Chrome bug/feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259887/google-chrome-doesnt-take-window-name-into-account).