# using window.open with window.name

Tags: javascript, window.open

The browser window.open method provides a way to access open windows by name. For example,

#### window A:

```
window.open('','myWindowName')
```

This will open a blank window B with window.name == 'myWindowName'. Then,

#### window C:

```
window.open('http://example.com', 'myWindowName')
```

This will open example.com in window B.

### The problem:

Rather than creating a new window with name == 'myWindowName', how can I set the name of an already opened window so that it can be accessed by other windows using window.open? Using Chrome the following does not work:

#### 1. open the following html in the target window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>window.name='myWindowName'</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    target window
  </body>
</html>
```

executing window.name in the target window now produces 'myWindowName'

#### 2. execute the following js from the console of another window

```
window.open('http://example.com', 'myWindowName')
```

The code above opens example.com in a new window (also with window.name 'myWindowName') rather than the target window.

#### edit:

for some reason, in chrome, setting the name in the target window will work if no content is loaded into the window, but once content is loaded setting window.name no longer affects the window.open of other windows.

Comment: What browser are you using? I just tried this in Chrome and it worked as you would expect: two tabs, `window.name = 'window1';` in one; `window.open('http://example.com', 'window1');` in the other opens "http://example.com" in the other tab, not a new tab. This also worked with separate windows instead of tabs.

Comment: Seems to work in firefox.

Comment: Works. http://jsfiddle.net/C5pFg/

Comment: when executing all js from blank chrome consoles the issue does not occur. thanks for pointing that out, sorry my testing didn't turn that up. Will edit the question so the problem is easier to reproduce.

Comment: Security reasons. Once the window left your domain, you lose any control over it and can't read or set any of its properties, same like with `<iframe>`. (except maybe closing it)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do not understand how this could be because if I open the target window using window.open('<pathtotarget>', 'myWindowName') then the target window moves to the target domain. But, I can still open content in the target window from window c with window.open('<pathtotarget>', 'myWindowName'). the problem only occurs when setting the window.name from the target window.

Comment: @natb1 will have to look deeper into it when having some time, but that's the direction I would look in.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10259887/3315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, in order to target a window by name using the window.open method, the target window must have the same origin AND have a common opener.

chrome test:

#### 1. open new window example.com (or any site)

```
window.name = 'target'
window.was_open = true
```

#### 2. open new window example.com (or any site)

```
w = window.open('', 'target')
w.was_open //undefined
```

It is unknown why the same test works when the js is executed in a window console without loading content first (like example.com).

A common window cannot be targeted from multiple origins, or windows with different openers. For example, window.open cannot be used by a bookmarklet to `postMessage()` to a common window.