# How to submit form to same window on target windowName?, When opener closed and reopen

Tags: javascript, html, forms

First, I open a **'FormWindow'** form attribute Target was set to **'targetWindow'**

```
<form ... target='targetWindow'>
```

Then **'targetWindow'** has opened , Then **'FormWindow'**.close();

Then I open a **'FormWindow'** again -> submit,

But **'targetWindow'** was duplicated

Tested on Firefox 52

My Question :

How to do that? Refer to only one window target and don't want to hold a form window.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: Possibly something to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822644/using-window-open-with-window-name